# emacs how to use call-interactively with parameter

Tags: emacs

If I want to make my own function which among other thing calls **wg-save** (workgroups.el - save workgroups) then I do something like this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  ...
  (call-interactively 'wg-save)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "my binding") 'foo)
```

What about the following scenario (I will use eyebrowse.el as an example):

eyebrowse uses C-c C-w 'number' to move to different window configurations e.g. C-c C-w 1 to move to 1 or C-c C-w 2 to move to 2.

How can I write a similar function like the 'foo' since now I need to pass to 'call-interactively' a 'number' as parameter?

EDIT: C-c C-w 1 calls eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config-1.
So I need to make a 'foo' function like the above that will 'call-interactively' 
'eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config-1' when the key binding is 'C-c C-w 1', 'eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config-2' when the key binding is 'C-c C-w 2' etc.
Something like the following (if it makes sense):

```
(defun foo ()
    (interactive)
    ...
    (call-interactively 'eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config-"number")
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-w 'number'") 'foo)
```

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation, read with `C-h f call-interactively RET`:

> Optional third arg KEYS, if given, specifies the sequence of events to
>   supply, as a vector, if the command inquires which events were used to
>   invoke it.  If KEYS is omitted or nil, the return value of
>   `this-command-keys-vector' is used.

So to pass arguments to `call-interactively`, give it a vector with the arguments, like so

```
(call-interactively 'my-fn t (vector arg1 arg2))
```

That way you don't need to call `eyebrowse-switch-to-config-window-n`where n is a number, you call the function they rely on, `eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config`, and give it a number as argument.

You can get a number for argument like this: (see help of "interactive" )

```
(defun foo (arg)
    (interactive "nWindow? ")
    (call-interactively 'my-fn t (vector arg))
)
```

But did you read the source of eyebrowse ? It will give ideas.

```
(defun eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config-0 ()
  "Switch to window configuration 0."
  (interactive)
  (eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I see now how to pass variables to call-interactively. Yes, I know about the functions called by eyebrowse (the last part of your answer). I also use C-h k to find the functions called. But I want to avoid making one custom function for each eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config-<number>. Now, how do I pass the 'arg' to the 'foo' function through a key binding? That is how can I do something like: (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-w-<number>") 'foo) so that 'foo' gets 'arg' and pass it to 'call-ineractively'?

Comment: What about doing with the universal argument, which is a parameter to "interactive", and the keybinding will look like `C-u <number> C-c C-w`

Comment: I know this approach. I am trying to make it work as the original one, "C-c C-w-<number>". Probably the best thing to do is to write a separate function for each binding: "C-c C-w-0", "C-c C-w-1", ... , "C-c C-w-9"

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this I believe:

```
(defun foo (NUM)
  "Enter the NUM of the screen to go to.
If the key pressed is not a number go to screen 0."
  (interactive
   (list (read-key-sequence "Which window: ")))
  ((eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config 3) (string-to-number NUM)))
```

The key is the `read-key-sequence` function

Answer (score 0):

To save time and space, you can use a loop to define all the keybindings you'll use.

For example, for eyebrowse instead of defining each keybinding you could do this instead:

```
(load-library "eyebrowse")
(dotimes (i 10)
  (global-set-key
   (kbd (concat "C-c C-w " (number-to-string i)))
   `(lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (eyebrowse-switch-to-window-config ,i))))
```